# Get sender's address in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that will auto reply with an pre-coded SMS to the sender. Sending a message is easy. My problem is I can't seem to get the message and get the sender's address/number. I have searched over and over and over for this answer. All I need is to know is how to get the sender's address and only the address. Nothing else is needed. Everything that I've tried to reference just throws a ton of code at me that I don't need. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098472/any-way-to-get-the-sender-phone-number-from-a-received-sms-on-android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are receiving the sms through the sms broadcast. You can extract the sender address from the intent. Example:

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. Was beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out.